# ActiveMQ cursorMemoryHighWaterMark having no effect

Tags: activemq-classic

I am trying to experiment with the effect of 'cursorMemoryHighWaterMark' on a destination.

I have a single producer connected to a single queue and the following config:

```
<systemUsage>
  <systemUsage>
    <memoryUsage>
      <memoryUsage limit="100 mb"/>
    </memoryUsage>
    <storeUsage>
      <storeUsage limit="512 mb"/>
    </storeUsage>
    <tempUsage>
      <tempUsage limit="100 mb"/>
    </tempUsage>
  </systemUsage>
</systemUsage>
```

and a policy entry on the destination:

```
<policyEntry queue=">" cursorMemoryHighWaterMark="30" />
```

As the memory usage limit is set to 100MB and the cursorMemoryHighWaterMark set to 30, I assumed that pushing 1MB non persistent messages (no consumers) on to the queue, they would be stored in memory until the memory usage reaches 30MB (30% of 100MB), then it would start spooling the messages to the temp storage directory.

This is not taking place until the memory usages hits 70MB, which tallies with the default cursorMemoryHighWaterMark of 70.

I have tried various things such as enabling/disabling PFC and also setting the memory limit on the destination itself, but I always get the same behaviour.

The version of ActiveMQ is 5.15.10

Am I not understanding the behaviour or is it a config issue, what am I missing here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like using fileQueueCursor has done the trick and

```
<policyEntry queue=">" cursorMemoryHighWaterMark="30">
  <pendingQueuePolicy>
    <fileQueueCursor />
  </pendingQueuePolicy>
</policyEntry>
```

Comment: I notice with these setting Temp percent used goes up even though only persistent messages were produced.  Any idea why?